# BUILD FAILURE in maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cygwin, cobertura

I am trying to build my `new-webapp` module using maven, and whenever I am doing `mvn install` from the command prompt using cygwin, it gives me this error -

```
$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building new-webapp MAIN
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.parent:test-logic:jar:MAIN is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.404s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 19 22:19:10 PST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project new-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.parent:new-webapp:jar:MAIN: Failure to find com.parent:test-logic:jar:MAIN in http://caucho.com/m2-snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of caucho.maven-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

And this `new-webapp` module depends on couple more dependency and from the above error it strike me that I need to build - `com.parent:test-logic:jar` dependency as well and then only I can build my `new-webapp`.

So I thought, I need to build that dependency (`com.parent:test-logic:jar`) first before doing `mvn install` on my `new-webapp`. So I went to my `test-logic` project and I ran the same command `mvn install` and this time I got different error and I am not sure how to fix that error -

```
[INFO] Cobertura 1.9.4.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Cobertura: Loaded information on 247 classes.

[ERROR] com.parent.logic.exception.AlreadyLockedException failed check. Line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 80.0%
com.parent.logic.util.LuaUtil$1 failed check. Line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 80.0%
com.parent.logic.dao.impl.UrlDAOReadOnlyImpl failed check. Branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 90.0%
com.parent.logic.dao.impl.UrlDAOReadOnlyImpl failed check. Line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 80.0%
com.parent.logic.service.CronService failed check. Branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 90.0%
com.parent.logic.service.CronService failed check. Line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 80.0%
com.parent.logic.msg.client.AppStoreResponse failed check. Branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 90.0%

----- some other errors like this

Project failed check. Total branch coverage rate of 0.0% is below 85.0%
Project failed check. Total line coverage rate of 0.0% is below 85.0%

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.424s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 19 22:18:42 PST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/249M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.2:check (default) on project mac-core: Coverage check failed. See messages above. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This is related with some cobertura maven plugin error. My `test-logic` project is using cobertura plugin. So is there any way while doing `mvn install` on `test-logic` project, I can skip all these cobertura things and `test-logic` project gets build properly?

If needed,I can provide the pom.xml file for `test-logic` project as well. if I can make this `test-logic` project build properly, then I might be able to build new-weabapp project as well.

My main goal is to build new-webapp project properly using mvn install and whenever I do, it always gives me the above mentioned error.

Any help on this would be really appreciated!!!
Thanks.

**UPDATE:-**

I just checked my pom. test-logic project doesn't have any cobertura thing..

Only my parent pom.xml has cobertura thing and it has two modules adeed, one for `new-webapp` and other for `logic`. Below is my pom.xml file -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
   <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
   <version>MAIN</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <name>Host-PC</name>

   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <release.version>MAIN</release.version>
      <cobertura.version>1.9.4</cobertura.version>
   </properties>

   <modules>
      <module>logic</module>
       <module>new-webapp</module>
   </modules>

   <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>caucho</id>
         <name>Caucho</name>
         <url>http://caucho.com/m2-snapshot</url>
      </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>

   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>caucho.maven-repo</id>
         <name>Caucho Repository</name>
         <url>http://caucho.com/m2-snapshot</url>
      </repository>
      <repository>
         <id>java.net-Public</id>
         <name>Maven Java Net Snapshots and Releases</name>
         <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
         <artifactId>resin</artifactId>
         <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.caucho</groupId>
         <artifactId>resin-javaee</artifactId>
         <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
         <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.4-1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
         <version>12.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
         <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
         <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
         <version>6.3</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-logic</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>


 <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>cobertura-instrument</id>
         <activation>
            <property>
               <name>cobertura-build</name>
            </property>
         </activation>
         <modules>
            <module>test-cobertura</module>
         </modules>
         <build>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                  <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.5.2</version>
                  <configuration>
                  </configuration>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>instrument-code</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <attach>true</attach>
                        </configuration>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
               </plugin>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2.1</version>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <inherited>true</inherited>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
             <artifactId>cobertura-runtime</artifactId>
               <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
               <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
         </dependencies>
      </profile>
   </profiles>


   <build>
      <finalName>test-${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</finalName>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>

      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>validate</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>create</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <useLastCommittedRevision>true</useLastCommittedRevision>
               <scmDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}</scmDirectory>
               <doCheck>false</doCheck>
               <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                  <phase>process-resources</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>manifest</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <supportedProjectTypes>
                  <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                  <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                  <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
               </supportedProjectTypes>
               <instructions>
                  <Build-version>${buildNumber}</Build-version>
               </instructions>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <instrumentation>
                  <includes>
                     <include>com/parent/**/*.class</include>
                  </includes>
                  <!--
                  <ignores>
                     <ignore>com.example.boringcode.*</ignore>
                  </ignores>
                  -->
                  <!--
                  <excludes>
                     <exclude>com/example/dullcode/**/*.class</exclude>
                     <exclude>com/example/**/*Test.class</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                  -->
               </instrumentation>
               <check>
                  <branchRate>85</branchRate>
                  <lineRate>85</lineRate>
                  <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                  <totalBranchRate>85</totalBranchRate>
                  <totalLineRate>85</totalLineRate>
                  <packageLineRate>85</packageLineRate>
                  <packageBranchRate>85</packageBranchRate>
                  <regexes>
                     <regex>
                        <pattern>com.parent.*</pattern>
                        <branchRate>90</branchRate>
                        <lineRate>80</lineRate>
                     </regex>
                  </regexes>
               </check>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>clean</goal>
                     <goal>check</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

   <reporting>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehause.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>codertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <formats>
                  <format>html</format>
                  <format>xml</format>
               </formats>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </reporting>


</project>
```

Comment: You should exclude the exception class from being checked by Cobertura - see http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html (as there is perhaps not much to unit-test on an exception)

Answer (score 0):

It might not work straight away as you didn't provide your `pom.xml`. However, please try to run `mvn` with the following parameter: `-DcoberturaHaltOnError=false`

Comment: :no, it didn't worked out. I have already tried that before and I get the same exception as I was getting before. I have updated my question with my pom.xml file. Let me know if there is anything else you might be needing..

Comment: Try to set <inherited>false</inherited> rather than true

Comment: I just tried that, still the same thing I am getting, same exception.. After making that false, I did `mvn clean install`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to insufficient test coverage, build not getting success. Reduce test coverage mentioned in the below tags and try.

85 & lineRate>85